# mysql-connector isn't finding com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

I'm working on a project that involves a java program accessing a mysql database and display that info on a tomcat page. I have it working on my local machine but I want it running on my Raspberry Pi 4 so it can act as a "server" but it's not connecting properly so I made a test program

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class YourClassName {
    public Connection connection;
    private String pw = "<password_here>"; // Password for DB server...
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://<ipaddress>/database?user=<myuser>&password=" + pw + "&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";

    public YourClassName() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); // Load the MySQL JDBC driver
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            YourClassName yourObject = new YourClassName();
            // Rest of your code...
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this I get an error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at YourClassName.<init>(YourClassName.java:11)
    at YourClassName.main(YourClassName.java:17)
```

I have my jar file set to the CLASSPATH by
`javac -cp .:/path/to/mysql-connector-java-8.1.0.jar ClassName.java java -cp .:/path/to/mysql-connector-java-8.1.0.jar ClassName`

mysql version is 8.0.34, mysql-connector is version 8.1.0. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Edit: I should also say I'm using Apache Tomcat. I'm compiling the program on my local machine and sending the WAR file to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What does this have to do with `javascript` tag?

Comment: @PrerakSola there's a jsp element to the project but I just need help with the mysql element.

Comment: Just FYI, **jsp** which is an abbreviation for `Jakarta Server Pages`, previously known as `JavaServer Pages` is completely different from **javascript**.

Comment: I tested your code with MySQL Connector/J 8.1.0. It works fine, I cannot reproduce the error. I can guess that perhaps you gave it the wrong path to your jar file.

Comment: @BillKarwin Hmm interesting. Should the jar be in a certain location then? Because I have the path set to where it's located on my machine.

Comment: Evidently you have not. Do you get the error on compilation, or executing the compiled class file, or both? (well I guess you can't get the error on both if you get the error on compile :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin only on execution

Comment: All I can suggest is that you mistyped the path on the second command. When I have experienced mysterious problems like this, I just re-type it carefully, and don't use command history or copy & paste. I may use tab completion to help get the path and filename right. Almost always the problem was that I had made a typo.

Comment: @BillKarwin I wish it was something like that xD. But no I used the same path for both commands. Thanks though.

Comment: This is *your code* not finding the class, not the MySQL Connector JDBC driver. The [tag:jsp] tag is completely irrelevant.

Comment: The MySQL JDBC driver JAR must either be in the WAR or in the server/lib folder on the Tomcat server installation.  Start with putting it in the JAR.  If you still get the error, open the JAR and make sure that's the correct fully resolved class name.

Comment: Using `-cp` with `javac` does not make it magically work when **running** your code, it only affects the classpath when **compiling** your code (and you don't even need to specify it when compiling, because you don't actually use any of those classes during compilation). The driver must be on the runtime class path (e.g. in the `WEB-INF/lib` of the WAR).

Comment: NB The `Class.forName()` line hasn’t been needed since 2906.

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: @Sneh Yep a few things. I downloaded the libmariadb-java library, I also gave my data base user all the same permissions as a root user and it worked! I'm pretty sure it was just a permissions issue.